# How to detect iPhone 6 (6 plus) on simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have found this nice defines:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

But when I run iPhone 6 simulator or iPhone 6 plus simulator it every time work as iPhone 5.

I have checked the screen size:

```
(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen]
<UIScreen: 0x7ffb3a402930; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7ffb3a520a80; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>
```

and seems everting is clear why it points me to iPhone 5 instead of iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: Have you added Default(Splash)? Seems like you haven't add it

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani, oh yep this is the same issue. thank you. I have added default images and it works good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the appropriate launch images so the app device/simulator starts using the real size and not a zoomed or emulated size, until you add a launch image for `Retina HD 5.5` and `Retina HD 4.7` you won't be using the new sizes.

Click the small grey arrow on the Launch Images Source in your Project General Settings and add the appropriate launch images.
[image]